# removing ^M and new line while reading XML document

Tags: xml, perl

I am reading a XML document using perl like below and writing into a text document

```
my $var = $line->find('tag1/tag2/tag3/tag4')->string_value
```

but the value ($var) contains ^M character and new line character in the middle of the string.

I tried chomp(`my $var = $line->find('tag1/tag2/tag3/tag4')->string_value`), but still ^M and new line character is not getting removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chomp` only removes a trailing Line Feed.

I'm assuming you mean Carriage Return when you say ^M.

```perl
$var =~ s/\r\n\z//;   # Remove trailing CR LF
$var =~ s/\r?\n\z//;  # Remove trailing CR LF or LF
$var =~ s/\s+\z//;    # Remove all trailing whitespace.

$var =~ s/\r//g;      # Remove all CR
$var =~ s/\r\n//g;    # Remove all CR LF
$var =~ s/\r?\n//g;   # Remove all CR LF or LF
```

Comment: I have ^M and new line character, in the middle of the string

Comment: I just noticed that and updated while you were commenting :)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the data between the two tags, it's up to you to decide how to handle the whitespace (although be careful if some whitespace is meant to carry meaning):

If you just want to handle carriage return and newlines, just replace them:

```
$value =~ s/[\r\n]+/\x20/g;
```

Typically I want to normalize all whitespace to a single space in these cases:

```
$value =~ s/\s+/\x20/g;
```

Sometimes I only want to get rid of vertical whitespace—newlines, carriage returns (not really vertical, but whatever, and a few others. That's the `\v` character-class shortcut:

```
$value =~ s/\v+/\x20/g;
```

Or, sometimes I want get rid of line endings, which isn't just vertical whitespace:

```
$value =~ s/\R+/\x20/g;
```

Comment: Typo? You wrote "That's the `\h` character-class shortcut:", but then you use `\v` on the next line.